# Disconnecting VPN in C# using DOTRAS

Tags: c#, vpn, dotras

I'm making a VPN connection using DOTRAS in C# by the click of a button, using the following method.

```
 string VpnName = "Test1";
            string Destination = "191.20.0.21";
            string PresharedKey = "myKey";
            RasPhoneBook PhoneBook = new RasPhoneBook();
            PhoneBook.Open();

            RasEntry VpnEntry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(VpnName, Destination, DotRas.RasVpnStrategy.L2tpOnly, DotRas.RasDevice.Create(VpnName, DotRas.RasDeviceType.Vpn));
            VpnEntry.Options.UsePreSharedKey = true;
            VpnEntry.Options.UseLogOnCredentials = true;
            VpnEntry.Options.RequirePap = true;
            VpnEntry.Options.RequireMSChap = false;
            VpnEntry.Options.RequireMSChap2 = false;
            PhoneBook.Entries.Add(VpnEntry);
            VpnEntry.UpdateCredentials(RasPreSharedKey.Client, PresharedKey);
            Console.WriteLine("VPN connected successfully");
```

The VPN connects successfully.
I need to **disconnect** it now (Something other than simply removing it).
 How will that be possible?

Answer (score 2):

here:

```
var conn = RasConnection.GetActiveConnections().Where(c => c.EntryName == "Test1").FirstOrDefault();
if (conn!=null)
{
    conn.HangUp();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.